# How to troubleshoot Veeam backup for MS Office 365 (v5) setup issues (Add Organization)?

Tags: office365, backup, veeam

about 6 months ago, I successfully set up a trial version of Veeam Backup for Microsoft Office 365 (since renamed Veeam Backup for Microsoft 365, with a new major version, and double the CPU requirements).

The client still needs to have the v5 version (due to the fact that their server lacks the requisite 8 cores to support the new v6 release).

I am now attempting to set up the software once again, and I am stumbling out of the gate.  When I attempt to "Add Organization", connecting to the M365 organization using the same (office 365) global admin user I used to create the original test, and the same setup choices for authentication (Basic), etc. now returns:

```
2022-05-11 8:57:13 PM :: Connect to Microsoft Graph: unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type
2022-05-11 8:57:13 PM :: Connect to EWS: The request failed with HTTP status 401: . :: 0:00:03
2022-05-11 8:57:17 PM :: Connect to SharePoint: unknown_user_type: Unknown User Type
2022-05-11 8:57:18 PM :: Connect to PowerShell: Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. :: 0:00:03
```

I figured this was a good time to set up a dedicated user for Veeam Backup for Office , so I am now have a new global admin, with exactly the same roles and permissions as the original one, plus and Office basic license.  Making the connection with this user (vbo@tenant.onmicrosoft.com) results in only two failures:

```
2022-05-11 9:00:53 PM :: Connect to EWS: The request failed with HTTP status 401: .
2022-05-11 9:00:56 PM :: Connect to PowerShell: Connecting to remote server outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : Access is denied. :: 0:00:08
```

I have not been able to find much in the way of troubleshooting information on the Veeam community site (I am attempting this with the community edition, which I downloaded back in December).  I am unable to open a support ticket with Veeam, since that requires license information from the application, and the sales people were unable to generate a second v5 trial license for me.

so - any guidance/thoughts welcome.

I have reviewed all the pre-requisites from the documentation (and nothing that I know of has changed on the server, anyway).  I repeated all the powershell steps from my setup notes, with the new vbo@... credentials.

I can successfully log on to https://office.microsoft.com with the new user and send and receive email, work in sharepoint, administer all the apps from the GUI, and so on.

Using the [Microsoft connectivity tester](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/o365), however, results in a failure. This is the Service Account Access (Developers) test:

```

Exchange Web Services service account access verification
The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer failed to complete all tests with the service account.
Test Steps

The Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer is attempting to test Autodiscover for userID@tenant.com.
Autodiscover was tested successfully.

Attempting to resolve the host name outlook.office365.com in DNS.
The host name resolved successfully.

Testing TCP port 443 on host outlook.office365.com to ensure it's listening and open.
The port was opened successfully.

Testing the SSL certificate to make sure it's valid.
The certificate passed all validation requirements.

A new mail item is being created.
The attempt to create a mail item failed.

Additional Details
Exception details:
Message: The request failed. The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Type: Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestException
Stack trace:
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.Save(FolderId parentFolderId)
   at Microsoft.M365.RCA.ConnectivityTests.CreateItemTest.PerformTestReally()

Exception details:
Message: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
Type: System.Net.WebException
Stack trace:
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EwsHttpWebRequest.Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.IEwsHttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.GetEwsHttpWebResponse(IEwsHttpWebRequest request)
```